# В динамическом массиве не сохраняются предыдущие элементы

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void show(int *array, int size);

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "RUS");

    int *p = NULL;
    int i = 0, size = 0, n;
    bool check = false;
    int flag;

    do {
        p = new int[size];
        cout << "Введите число: ";
        cin >> n;
        size++;
        p[i++]=n;
        cout << "Продолжить? Yes=1, No=0: ";
        cin >> flag;
        if (flag != 1)
            check = false;
        else
            check = true;
    } while (check == true);

    show(p, size);

    return 0;
}

void show(int *array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << array[i] << '\t';
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а чего вы ждали? `p = new int[size];` - каждый раз массив заного создаётся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы зря выделяете память на массив заного, вам может помочь `realloc` Пример использования:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int * b = (int * ) malloc( sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
        b = (int *) realloc(b, (i+1) * sizeof(int)); // не пишите так!!
        b[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
        cout << b[i] << " "; 
    return 0;
}
```

Это классический С - style. Писать так нужно аккуратно, если память не будет выделена то испортится указатель на старую память.

Про оптимизацию молчу, это ресурсоёмкий код.

Comment: благодарю, а сточку  b = (int *) realloc(b, (i+1) * sizeof(int)) в стиле с++ можно записать как-то?

Comment: это правильная строка для С++, просто она опасная, снизу пояснено почему. В учебном задании так можно делать но в реальнх проектах нет.

Comment: `realloc` на `new`?! Нельзя такое мешать!

Comment: @alexolut я слышал об этом, но ни разу не сталкивался с проблемами, это как-то связано с парами malloc/free new/delete?

Comment: Сугубо попарное использование, да. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4061522/3240681